# System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() in Windows 10 Universal App

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10, win-universal-app

I know, there is an issue with System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() in the Portable Class Libraries. To overcome it, I have decided to extract the list of assemblies in the target application and send it to my PCL as custom objects.

This was easy when using single-platform applications (pure WinForms, pure WP 8 application, etc.). However, I cannot find any suitable replacement for the method in Windows 10 Universal apps (and the documentation for both PCLs and Win 10 Universal Apps is pretty bad, so far). The reason, why PCLs are not able to get a list of assemblies is simply because the library does not know of all the assemblies, until it is built and packed into DLL. However, that cannot be said of the Universal App, since it should run the same system (Windows 10) -> therefore, it should be the same program on both PC and Phone -> therefore, the application should know of all its assemblies already before compiling.

So, does there exist a suitable replacement for this method, or some workaround how to get all the assemblies inside the app?

EDIT: I have found [this workaround](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6e8d015b-4c3b-4e1a-9884-d986ba5935c0/appdomain-assembly-enumeration?forum=winappswithcsharp), which loops through all .dll and .exe files... however, that seems extremely unreliable. Is there a cleaner/better way?

Comment: As i know, currently there is no way to get assemblies list at runtime. You should manually create the list of assemblies (`typeof(TypeDefinedInAssembly).GetTypeInfo().Assembly`) and pass it to your PCL library.

Comment: Yes, but this would require calling the method GetTypeInfo() on at least one type from each assembly in the application, wouldn't it?

Comment: If you really need all assemblies than yes.

Comment: `The reason, why PCLs are not able to get a list of assemblies is simply because the library does not know of all the assemblies, until it is built and packed into DLL.` - this has nothing to do with compile-time information. `GetAssemblies` is a runtime call.

Comment: If that is true, then I do not understand, why it is not supported.